# iOS 14: UI extension crashes upon startup

Tags: ios, ios-extensions

I am developing the UI extension, it works correctly with iOS 15, but crashes upon startup on devices running iOS 14. To my understanding, the presented log implies that crash occurs before the extension's code is executed, so I can't fix the code itself to solve the issue (but I am not a professional iOS developer, so...).

Partial crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 90720807-BB29-40B0-99EA-FCF7D9347CB4
CrashReporter Key:   318d9685fef2ea9c117d9f313ee2a7abc8de6187
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,1
Process:             OWExtension [2853]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/946320B4-00EB-4DFA-9D83-498BF85B6E89/App.app/PlugIns/OWExtension.appex/OWExtension
Identifier:          com.example.ow.OWExtension
Version:             10 (9.99)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.example.ow.OWExtension [4266]


Date/Time:           2022-01-12 15:51:59.1501 +0300
Launch Time:         2022-01-12 15:50:16.3811 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.6 (18F72)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.05.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000af7aec290
VM Region Info: 0xaf7aec290 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 35830809233  Bytes before following region: 20540636528
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO              280000000-2a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
---&gt;  GAP OF 0xd20000000 BYTES
      commpage (reserved)      fc0000000-1000000000 [  1.0G] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [2853]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001982c2c80 objc_retain + 16
1   UIKitCore                       0x0000000185de7634 _UISetCurrentFallbackEnvironment + 72
2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001866066c8 -[_UIViewServiceViewControllerOperator __createViewControllerWithOptions:completionBlock:] + 588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183803774 __invoking___ + 148
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836d6d44 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 380
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836d7348 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 80
6   UIKitCore                       0x0000000186611170 -[_UIViewServiceImplicitAnimationDecodingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 108
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183800fe8 ___forwarding___ + 736
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001838035b0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183803774 __invoking___ + 148
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836d6d44 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 380
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836d7348 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 80
12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001865f7464 -[_UIQueueingProxy forwardInvocation:] + 376
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183800fe8 ___forwarding___ + 736
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001838035b0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183803774 __invoking___ + 148
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836d6d44 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 380
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836d7348 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 80
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183800fe8 ___forwarding___ + 736
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001838035b0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
20  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183803774 __invoking___ + 148
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001836d6d44 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 380
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833eb81c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833ef30c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 268
24  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000192de3fa0 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
25  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000192de3c30 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 448
26  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000192de4184 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 32
27  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001837789e8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
28  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001837788e4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183777be8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183771bc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 820
31  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183771360 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
32  GraphicsServices                0x000000019adaf734 GSEventRunModal + 164
33  UIKitCore                       0x00000001861ec584 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072
34  UIKitCore                       0x00000001861f1df4 UIApplicationMain + 168
35  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001cf391ba4 _xpc_objc_main + 600
36  libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001cf393f1c xpc_main + 180
37  Foundation                      0x0000000184a94a18 +[NSXPCListener serviceListener] + 0
38  PlugInKit                       0x00000001b420f71c 0x1b41f5000 + 108316
39  PlugInKit                       0x00000001b420f344 0x1b41f5000 + 107332
40  PlugInKit                       0x00000001b420fb34 0x1b41f5000 + 109364
41  ExtensionKit                    0x0000000187ce5fe8 EXExtensionMain + 84
42  Foundation                      0x0000000184be370c NSExtensionMain + 200
43  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018342dcf8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001cf369744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001cf369744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b18f04fc mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b18ef884 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183777eb0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183771d50 __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183771360 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   Foundation                      0x0000000184a5efdc -[NSRunLoop+ 32732 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232
6   Foundation                      0x0000000184a5eea8 -[NSRunLoop+ 32424 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001862a112c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 516
8   Foundation                      0x0000000184bd032c __NSThread__start__ + 864
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001cf360bfc _pthread_start + 320
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001cf369758 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001cf369744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001cf369744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000028313c270   x1: 0x00000001d2e24964   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001026e454c
    x4: 0x000000000000001c   x5: 0x000000010288f9a0   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x000000000000003e
    x8: 0x0000368af7aec270   x9: 0x0000000af7aec270  x10: 0x02000001e5d82d39  x11: 0x03000001e5d82d39
   x12: 0x0000000000524980  x13: 0x00000001e5d24f80  x14: 0x0002000110000550  x15: 0x00000001e5d24f80
   x16: 0x00000001982c2c70  x17: 0x00000001833eacac  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000283130000
   x20: 0xb5783ab44021d400  x21: 0x0000000109009400  x22: 0x00000001e64656a8  x23: 0x0000000280a280c0
   x24: 0x0000000283130000  x25: 0x0000000282e34300  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x00000001d2cb7ae4
   x28: 0x00000002829281e0   fp: 0x000000016d9917a0   lr: 0x0000000185de7634
    sp: 0x000000016d991750   pc: 0x00000001982c2c80 cpsr: 0x20000000
   esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault
```

Usinng Zombie objects during another debug session I was able to get the following message (I removed the actual address since it does not belong to the presented log)

```
[UITraitCollection retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x...
```

Maybe someone could shed some light on what's going on here?

Comment: without your code, it's hard to understand what's happened

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Basically this issue reproduces even if I am creating an empty ViewController and trying to launch it in a designated way. I can't share the code since it uses Apple In-App Provisioning API, which could not be disclosed.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to found out what was the issue? I'm struggling with the same issue as you do.

Comment: @IgorDymov: We are also facing same crash issue. Could you please share what could be the root cause of crash ?

Comment: @YoBo: are you able to fix this issue ?

Comment: Yes, I did. We contacted apple and they confirmed that the UI extension is not working on iOS 14. You should use iOS 15+ for the extension. Their documentation is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

For those facing this issue, we reached out to Apple and received confirmation that the UI extension isn't functioning properly on iOS 14. To utilize the extension, it's necessary to make it available on iOS 15 or later. It seems that their documentation might be misleading on this matter.